# Suspicious MySQL warnings in Windows logs: what's happening there?

Tags: mysql, windows, security, warnings

I found many warnings in the Server Manager's Windows Logs with messages like:

```
Host name 'dynamic.vdc.vn' could not be resolved: No such host is known.
```

or

```
IP address '125.78.30.30' has been resolved to the host name '30.30.78.125.broad.qz.fj.dynamic.163data.com.cn', which resembles IPv4-address itself.
```

Where do these warnings come from? Is this a security problem? 
Is my server trying to contact those servers and if yes: why?
What can I do against it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are records of other hosts establishing connections to your server. MySQL can be configured, and yours is configured, to try to use DNS to look up hosts that connect.

You may want to review your firewall and account security settings.